# How to use robot_localization correctly?

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I would like to ask you opinions and best practices of using the `robot_localization` package for the following use case:

- The vehicle has two wheels (left and right), more accurately two tracks (a robotic vehicle for agriculture).
- Eventually I will have to achieve automatic GPS waypoint finding.
- The wheels have fairly accurate encoders, so I can measure travelled distance and speed of both left and right tracks, calculate and publish `Odometry` messages from that with at least 10Hz.
- The vehicle is equipped with a navigational device which provides me GPS latitude, longitude and orientation (roll, pith, yaw) and speed. I can use these data to calculate and publish another `Odometry` message. Latitude and longitude is updated with 1Hz, orientation is updated with 10Hz.

I'm planning to fuse these two odometry sources with one `ekf_localization_node` and use its output for the waypoint finding. I'm wondering if this is a viable approach to do this or there would be a better way?

Many thanks,
Tamás

**EDIT 23/08/2020:** I have updated my setup based on the answers from @tom-moore (see below and other posts). It's available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/tbondar/ros-study-01), just on case it will be useful for someone.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344152/how-to-use-robot_localization-correctly?/) by [tbondar](https://answers.ros.org/users/50735/tbondar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2020-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems viable to me. Are you doing the conversion of the GPS data into your world frame coordinates, are are you using `navsat_transform_node`? Make sure the IMU adheres to the [specifications](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/preparing_sensor_data.html#imu) in the `r_l` wiki. The package isn't great at handling IMU and GPS only fusion, so the fact that you have encoders will help you immensely.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2020-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tbondar](https://answers.ros.org/users/50735/tbondar/) on 2020-07-07**:
Sorry about the delay, there's been a pause in the project, like in everything. I don't plan to use the `navsat_transform_node` because I don't have direct access to the GPS and IMU inside my navigational device. It reports *lat, long* and *orientation (yaw)* values directly and I don't have access to the details. I'll have to put together the `Odometry` message myself from these. Does this change your opinion regarding feasibility?

I guess the covariances will be the most challenging. I will probably have to ask further questions when I'll get there.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2020-07-14**:
If it gives you lat/long/orientation, you should still be able to use `navsat_transform_node`, but you may need a translation node so it outputs the right message types for consumption by `navsat_transform_node`. But as long as your GPS conversion outputs usable world-frame coordinates, you should be fine, absolutely. Just fuse pose data from your GPS (or GPS conversion node) and velocity data from the wheel encoders.

**Comment by [tbondar](https://answers.ros.org/users/50735/tbondar/) on 2020-08-23**:
@tom-moore Thanks for your reply, I've updated my setup according to your suggestions here and other posts. I've uploaded it with a simple vehicle emulator to GitHub (link above in my original post). My current node graph is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tbondar/ros-study-01/master/docs/rqt_graph_01.png). Would you mind having a quick look just in case you spot something incorrect?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2020-08-31**:
Is anything misbehaving, or is it working as expected? I don't have the cycles to dig into it right now, but if there are specific issues, feel free to ask new questions.